# get the parameters entered when the program is runed from thecommand line?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am a beginner in C# and I recently wanted to develop a program that starts from the command line with some parameters.

Suppose I have a console program now
I run it from the command line and provide some parameters ，I need to get  `-d "D:\output\"`

```
C:\Program Files\myprogram.exe -d "D:\output\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // your code here; 'args' has the command line arguments
        // i.e. args will be length 2, args[0]==="-d", etc
       
    }
}
```